# Applying [ViewStateModeById] functionality to standard, dynamic ASP.net controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to ASP.net, the ViewState, and C# in general.

I have some code that adds and deletes boolean constraints that will later be submitted as an SQL query. I dynamically create these constraints with unique IDs. When I delete a constraint earlier that was added before some other constraint, the viewstate tries to map the contents of the DropDownList that was deleted to the DropDownList immediately below it.

This is turn triggers an index changed event and causes undesirable behavior in the application. I'm fairly certain that this behavior is caused because the ViewState loads the postback data into dynamically created controls via index.

I've  been searching for a solution came across [ViewStateModeById] as a possible solution. Unfortunately, this seems to only to custom controls. I would like to avoid creating new custom controls for everything just to index the controls by ID.

Is there a way to gain this functionality without having creating custom controls?

I should mention that each dynamically generated constraint (which is a set of about 5 controls) is inside a dynamically generated panel. I could just keep creating empty panels as a sort of placeholder to get my desired behavior, but that is just a hack. I'll end up with many, many panels unless I implement another hack to occasionally delete some of my panels.

Comment: ViewStateModeByIdAttribute applies not only to control itself, but also to its direct children. E.g. if you will create a custom placeholder, decorate it with ViewStateModeById, its direct children will get this behavior. As a workaround for your problem, put each DropDownList inside such custom placeholder (or maybe decorate their parent panel you mentioned in last paragraph, can't say for sure without knowing whole thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled with the viewstate until I got it. This is not a real answer but when working with viewstate it is very important that the dynamic controls created gets the **exact same id** after each post back. It means that you'll have to re-create/re-bind everything on each post pack.

If it does I'd be surprised if you get strange behaviors and you should be able to code almost like if it was a desktop app.

Comment: They are created with the exact same ID. That was my previous conception of how the ViewState worked. Apparently though, it is done by index in the control structure tree. This concept is evident in what I've read and is revealed in the problems I have not when i try to delete dynamic controls out of my hierarchy. If I remember correctly, this applies to everything except TextBox's. I'm trying to figure out a way

Comment: Where did you get the "by index" from? I'd like to read that too. I'm pretty sure it's by id and you can add things between also changing the index. Maybe you can share some code where you get the behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically adding web controls to the page's control tree and later deleting some of them seems a bit strange to me.

But anyway, if you want to get rid of already existing controls in the control tree, you could just set their Visible property to false. Controls having Visible==false are not rendered to the client and thus behave almost like they wouldn't exist at all.

Or, what about creating them dynamically without immedialetly adding them to an actual control tree?
You could e.g. add and remove references to and from the Context.Items collection at any time during the page request and finally add just the ones you need.